# Same command sent locally works, but not when sent remotely?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, graph

I wonder if someone can help, I’m targeting the same host with the following graph command..

Which executes fine when I’m logged on directly to the host.
(ignore the standard graph_cli error)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ graph shared/feed.csv -y 9,10 --ylabel Temp --title CabinTemp --figsize 1600x1000 --output shared/zzzz07.png

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_converter.py:129: FutureWarning: Using an implicitly registered datetime converter for a matplotlib plotting method. The converter was registered by pandas on import. Future versions of pandas will require you to explicitly register matplotlib converters.

To register the converters:
        >>> from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
        >>> register_matplotlib_converters()
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)
```

But when I try to send it to the same host, via another machine using this ssh command, (which works for other commands)

```
root@MiOS_54321:/# ssh -i /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key pi@192.168.1.37 graph shared/feed.csv -y 9,10 --ylabel Temp --title CabinTemp --figsize 1600x1000 --output shared/zzzz07.png
```

I get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/graph", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main.main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graph_cli/main.py", line 10, in main
    graphs = get_graph_defs(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graph_cli/graph.py", line 171, in get_graph_defs
    graphs, globals = read_chain(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graph_cli/graph.py", line 194, in read_chain
    data = stdin.buffer.read()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

Does anyone have any ideas what the issue / fix might be ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the remote host is running Python 2, while your local host is running Python 3.  In Python 3, the `sys.stdin` object has a `buffer` attribute:

```
$ python3
[...]
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.buffer
<_io.BufferedReader name='<stdin>'>
```

But this attribute does not exist in Python 2:

```
$ python2
[...]
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdin.buffer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

It looks as if the code you're running requires Python 3. It's possible the remote host does have Python3 available if you explicitly run it using e.g. `python3` or `pip3`, etc, but that's something you'll have to check.

Comment: Hi, thanks but forgive the perhaps stupid question- but isn’t the command being run on the same device ? One route is sent direct, while the other called/sent via a remote machine (target is always the same ) ?

Comment: I may have misread your question, when you said "when I try to send it remotely from another machine"; I didn't realize you were targeting the same host. In any case, the problem is still the same (python3 vs python2), but it may be due to something in your environment. Can you update your question to show the output of `which graph` locally, and the same command when executed remotely?

Comment: Thanks - I’ve updated it, hopefully  it’s clearer., and yes to confirm the target is always the same host - it’s just in the second example I’m trying to call it I while I’m at the command line (via ssh) of another machine .

Answer (score 0):

The owner of graph_cli (https://github.com/mcastorina/graph-cli/issues/39 ) has provided me with the answer..

> graph-cli attempts to detect if data is being piped into it or not for
> the chaining feature. So when you run it from an interactive session,
> isatty() is True. When you execute from a non-interactive ssh command,
> isatty() is False. That's why it is happening.
>
> The same would happen if you run echo | graph ....
>
> The full ssh command you should try is:
>
> ssh -t -i /etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key pi@192.168.102.37 'graph
> shared/feed.csv -y 9,10 --ylabel Temp --title CabinTemp --figsize
> 1600x1000 --output shared/zzzz08.png'